# Calibrating the output voltage 3

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

find the output voltageVo 
sole it please

Comment: i need to solve it

Comment: -1: total lack of effort, even when prompted. Not even the effort of posting a decent photo instead of that crappy mess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework problems without a demonstrated attempt at a solution are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

The path to a solution:

- Learn the meaning of [calibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration). What you want us to do is a [calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculation).
- As the hint says, look at this as two separate amplifier circuits then compute the differential voltage.
- Identify the upper stage as a non-inverting amplifier. Look for it's transfer function [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_3.html).
- Identify the lower stage as an inverting amplifier. Look for it's transfer function [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_2.html).
- Take the difference between the two.
- Electrical engineering is difficult but rewarding. You need to put a lot of effort into your studies.